# Do I need a HashSet or a Set?

Tags: haskell

I want to initialise a set of all Ints from 1 to n (n<20000). Then I want to remove them one by one and meanwhile check if certain elements are still in it until the set is empty.

Which data structure is suited best for this task?

Comment: Best in terms how long it takes? or how much memory it requires? or ease of writing the code?

Comment: @chepner my primary concern is time, but the other ones are also important

Comment: Try both and measure. Although tbh I suspect with such a small set it's not going to make a huge difference either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a bitset (a.k.a. `Integer`). A `1` bit represents a value still in the set; a `0` bit represents one that just ain't there. For example, the `Integer` that represents having all the numbers from `1` to `n` would be `bit (n+1) - 2` (assuming you plan to use 0-indexing, as seems sensible to me); to check whether a number is in the set, use `testBit`; to remove a number, use `clearBit`.

An alternate implementation strategy for the same underlying idea would be to use an unboxed array of `Bool`, either mutable or immutable as needed. The unboxed versions do the appropriate bit-packing. The only downside would be possibly having to resize the array if you need to add numbers to the set later that are larger than you originally allocated space for.

Comment: Wait, what? An unboxed `MArray` of `Bool` makes sense. And unboxed `MVector` of `Bool` stores one value per *byte*. Using immutable arrays or `Integer` for this sounds pretty inefficient to me given the size.

Comment: @dfeuer I didn't suggest using an `MVector` of `Bool`, so that one appears to be a strawman. As for efficiency, I guess it's probably worth doing some profiling after all. In any case `Integer` should be quite space-efficient: I compute roughly 2.5kb for an `Integer`, whereas a `Set Int` or `HashSet Int` is likely to be in the hundreds of kb range.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that you included `MVector` in the generic "mutable array". I would recommend neither `Set Int` nor `HashSet Int`. But `IntSet` is another story altogether, since it's a tree of bitsets. I'll explain in my answer how to avoid initialization cost for `IntSet` if that's important.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stick to immutable data structures, I would recommend `IntSet`. It's carefully optimized for precisely this kind of thing. A `Set Int` is a balanced binary search tree of `Int`s, which takes a lot of space and a good bit of time. A `HashSet Int` is an array-mapped trie of `Int`s, which is likely faster and more compact, but still pretty mediocre. An `IntSet` is a PATRICIA tree whose leaves are bitsets. So it's pretty compact (a little over twice the size of an unboxed immutable array when full), but much more efficient to modify.

Initializing an `IntSet` with all `Int`s from `1` to `n` takes `O(n)` time. If you're only initializing once, or once in a while, and `n < 20000`, then that shouldn't cause any performance trouble. If, however, you need to initialize often (especially if you sometimes only remove a few elements before discarding the set), or `n` turns out to be much larger (e.g., hundreds of millions) and you want to cut down on initialization time, you can use `IntSet` to represent the *complement* of the set you want to store.

```
data CompSet = CompSet
  { initialMax :: !Int
  , size :: !Int
  , missingElements :: !IntSet
  }
```

A `CompSet` stores the initial maximum (`n`), and an `IntSet` indicating which elements in `[1..initialMax]` are *no longer* in the set. The size of the `CompSet` is initialized to `initialMax` and lets you know in `O(1)` time whether the set is empty (i.e., when `size missingElements = initialMax`).